# UISwipeGestureRecognizer not registering swipe when used with UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have two recognizers for my view controller:

(viewDidLoad)

```
//Add gestures
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:nil];
    [tap setDelaysTouchesBegan:YES];
    tap.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:nil];

    leftSwipe.delegate = self;

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:leftSwipe];
```

On tap I want something to happen, on swipe I want to do something else. However the tap always calls both the swipe gesture and the tap gesture.

How can I make it so it calls either depending on the action?

Here is the code where I attempt to discern (but fail)

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{


    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UISwipeGestureRecognizer class]]) {

        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rg = (UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer;
        if (rg.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight && !self.itemsOnScreen) {
            NSLog(@"swipe");
            return YES;
        }else{
            return NO;

        }

    }

    if (self.itemsOnScreen) {

        self.itemsOnScreen = NO;

        //Actions for my tap

        return YES;

    }else{
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make different method for tap and swipe and set as **action** for each,

You can do something like,

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap:)];
    [tap setDelaysTouchesBegan:YES];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipe:)];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:leftSwipe];

}
- (IBAction)tap:(id)sender
{

    NSLog(@"taptap");
}
- (IBAction)swipe:(id)sender
{

    NSLog(@"swipe");
}
```

I have tested this is works for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Recommendation**

You might want to implement the following Gesture Recognizer Delegate method in addition to the recommendation noted by others:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer  shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

and possibly...

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

Here is the link to the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

There is a calback method on UIGestureRec...

```
// called when the recognition of one of gestureRecognizer or otherGestureRecognizer would be blocked by the other
// return YES to allow both to recognize simultaneously. the default implementation returns NO (by default no two gestures can be recognized simultaneously)
//
// note: returning YES is guaranteed to allow simultaneous recognition. returning NO is not guaranteed to prevent simultaneous recognition, as the other gesture's delegate may return YES
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer;
```

This should solve your problems